# Generating a global include graph in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Doxygen can generate graphs showing which files in a project `include` which others, as a directed graph. This is a nice tool, but it only comes in two flavors, namely showing all the files that include (directly or indirectly) a given file, or all the files that are included (again directly or indirectly) by a given file.

I would like to generate a global include graph, containing all the files that Doxygen knows about, and showing the include structure. Is that possible?

One trick that kind of works but feels extremely dirty: add some `dummy.h` header somewhere, and `include` it from every other file, or alternatively (a bit cleaner since it doesn't need to touch the other files) have `dummy.h` manually include everything else. And then manually remove useless includes (which are implied by others as indirect dependencies). That is not the right way to do it...

Comment: I believe it needs a root because it's displaying a tree and every edge is a dependency. What you want is several trees that may not be connected at all. (I thought of 'forest' but that's still connected.) A dummy would at least be a root to graph, but the focus of that graph would be a fake root and fake dependencies right next to real ones. My best advice to anyone who finds this is to use stub files to actually connect your components. If they belong in a dependency graph together there must be some connection to model.